# How to get Users who only have some specific department id, Linq

Tags: linq

I have following two entities

```
public class User
{
   public int UserId { get; set; }
   public string UserName { get; set; }
   public List<Department> Departments { get; set; }
}

public class Department
{
   public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
   public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
   public List<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

As you see, relationship between two objects is M:N.
I wanna get User who only have specific department ID, in this case, How to get users using Linq?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is just LINQ to Objects, isn't it?

Comment: I am testing on linq to object but, it could be linq to sql

Comment: Is there any differences if it goes for Linq To Sql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int requiredId = ...   
var usersInReqdDept = Users.Where(u => u.Departments
                                        .Any(d => d.DepartmentId == requiredId));
```

If the `Departments` list can be `null`, you will need a null-check in the `Where` clause.

If you want to search the  `Departments` list instead,

```
int requiredId = ...   
var usersInReqdDept = Departments.Single(d => d.DepartmentId == requiredId)
                                 .Users;
```

Of course, this will throw an exception if such a department doesn't exist.